# JavaScript, debugger doesn't show an error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying display 2 different characters, but it doesn't work. It only shows one of the characters. (first letter - 8 times by 1 letter, second letter on a different line - 8 times by 3 letters).

For example:

```
  i       i          i   i

ttt ttt ttt ttt
```

Could someone help please?

```html
<script>
  function rainbow() {
    var temp = "";
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        temp += "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp";
      }
      temp += document.getElementById("dead_rainbow").value
    }

    var pop = "";
    var k, l;
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
      for (l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
        pop += "&nbsp" + "&nbsp";
      }
      pop += document.getElementById("dead_unicorn").value
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "&nbsp" + temp;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "&nbsp" + pop;
  }
</script>

<input id="dead_unicorn" type="text" />&nbsp Character For Candles<br>
<input id="dead_rainbow" type="text" />&nbsp Character For Menorah<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="rainbow()">Run</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: On the two last lines of your function, you are basically doing `x = 't'; x = 'i';` You are overwriting the value. If you want to display both, you could do `...innerHTML = temp + '<br>' + pop;`

Comment: Do you want to have those two letters on two different lines, or more like tttittti...?

Comment: yes, on a 2 different lines

Comment: Ah sorry - you already mentioned that in your question. Now I'm just unsure how it should look. In the second line **ttt** followed by a space, and at the spot of the space an **i** in the first line, then move a space to the right and again **ttt** in the second line?

Comment: yes, ttt, space, ttt, space, ttt ..

Comment: Of course but where exactly should it start displaying the **i**s? Above the space of the **ttt**s?

Comment: yes  is are above of the ttts

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand well your question but is this what you need ? if not let me know in order to adjust the script: so my understanding is:

input 1 = i

input 2 = j

result :

i    i    i    i    i    i    i    i   (8 times)

jjj  jjj  jjj  jjj  jjj  jjj  jjj  jjj (8 times)

if this is correct so try this solution:

```html
<script>
  function rainbow() {
    var temp = "";
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        temp += "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp";
      }
      temp += document.getElementById("dead_rainbow").value;
    }

    var pop = "";
    var k, l;
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
      for (l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
        pop += "&nbsp" + "&nbsp";
      }
      secondVal = document.getElementById("dead_unicorn").value
      pop += secondVal + secondVal + secondVal;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "&nbsp" + temp + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "&nbsp" + pop;
  }
</script>

<input id="dead_unicorn" type="text" />&nbsp Character For Candles<br>
<input id="dead_rainbow" type="text" />&nbsp Character For Menorah<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="rainbow()">Run</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: your debugger doesn't show an error because there is no - at least from a syntactical point of view. Your problem is inside the logic.

As blex already mentioned the most predominate is this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "&nbsp" + temp;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "&nbsp" + pop;
```

I guess you might have thought this will simply add-up the strings and ultimately be assigned to the `.innerHTML` property of your `<div>`. Well that's not the case. With the `=` operator you're assigning a new value - so the second call will wipe out what was there previously. You can add the two strings (and possibly a new line tag) and assign it in one go:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "&nbsp" + temp + pop;
```

Your for-loop seems a bit overloaded. To simplify I'd recommend creating a 'pattern' by code, which you simply repeat using a simpler for-loop.

So in pseudo-code:

```
My-result=[empty]
My-pattern= ttt[space]
for a=0 to 8
My-result = My-result + My-pattern
```

Now unfortunately I'm not sure what you want the result to look like. I think you want to have the single characters right above the space in between the groups of three letters. With a standard font this is not exactly possible because the width of individual characters is not the same. As a result it will look a little something like this:

[image]

As you can see the letters drift apart. Compensation is usually done by using a monospace font. That's a font where e.g. the space character and the i character (as well as all other characters) are of equal width.

You can fake it by putting equal characters in between your desired characters on both lines and make them invisible.

Here's an example:

```js
function rainbow() {
  var letterA = document.getElementById("dead_rainbow").value;
  var letterB = document.getElementById("dead_unicorn").value;
  var myResult = "";
  var myPattern = "<span style='visibility:hidden;'>" + letterA + letterA + letterA + "</span>" + letterB;
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    myResult += myPattern;
  }
  myResult += "<br>";
  myPattern = letterA + letterA + letterA + "<span style='visibility:hidden;'>" + letterB + "</span>";

  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    myResult += myPattern;
  }


  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myResult;
}
```

```html
<input id="dead_unicorn" type="text" />&nbsp Character For Candles<br>
<input id="dead_rainbow" type="text" />&nbsp Character For Menorah<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="rainbow()">Run</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```